# aggregate hours minutes seconds text columns to time - Excel

Tags: excel, formatting

I have 3 columns formatted as text: hours, minutes, seconds
I need to consolidate them in a time format
e.g.

```
1  34  56 -> I need a cell with 1:34:56

23 02  11 -> 23:02:11
```

Is this possible without macro/code?
I had issues with escaping the colon

Comment: `=CONCATENATE(A1,":",B1,":",C1)` - is that code? What escaping issues did you have?

Comment: that made it :) I think I was missing the comma.

Comment: Doing that the concatenation approach will leave your time a text and not truly a time a far as most excel manipulations and math functions will be concerned.  I suggest you follow the TIME function answer posted by OldUgly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look up the "TIME" built in function? See the screen shot ...

[image]